# Intellij ShortCut

Tags: intellij-idea

If my code is like the following:

```java
    public void run(){
        line 1
        ...
        line n
    }
```

If my cursor is at the middle of the function body, how do I quickly jump to the line of the function declaration (`public void run(){`)?

Answer (score 0):

It is "Previous Method" action. B default, it is invoked by "Ctrl+Shift+Up":

[image]

Comment: Yes, the "Previous Method" action, bot not always <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.